# Concurrency within a single lambda@edge instance?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

My understanding is that a single lambda@edge instance can only handle one request at a time, and AWS will spin up new instances if all existing instances are serving a request.

My lambda has a heavy instance startup cost (~2 seconds) but a very light execution cost.  It triggers on viewer requests, which always come in batches of ~20 (loading a single-page application).  This means one user loading the app, on a cold start, will start ~20 lambda instances and take ~2 seconds.

But due to the very light execution cost, a single lambda instance could handle all 20 requests and it would still take only ~2 seconds.

An extra advantage is, since each instance connects to a 3rd party service on startup, there would be only 1 open connection instead of 20.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda@edge doesn’t support reserved nor provisioned concurrency.

Here is the link to the documentation for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html#lambda-at-edge-function-restrictions

That being said, with 2s cold start, you might consider using standard lambda.

Also, can’t you reduce that cold start somehow?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the concurrency restriction - I've looked at that restriction page but hadn't noticed that particular one.  The 2 sec latency is from connecting to the 3rd party service and receiving a payload - which I need to do before I can handle any requests, and I can't control the format/size of the payload, nor that service provider's efficiency, so it's hard to avoid sadly.

Comment: That payload from 3rd party. Is it always the same? Can’t you make a request and cache the data is Dynamodb or elsewhere?

Comment: Sadly it may change while my lambda is not running, so unfortunately not.  There's still things I could do... I could make periodic requests using e.g. cron to keep my lambda alive, or I could run some proxy between my lambda and the 3rd party service which is more responsive. Anyway, I was hoping for a quicker & neater solution.

Comment: Even though there may be workarounds for my case, I think it shows that lambda@edge is missing an important setting. To process X concurrent requests, your lambda startup code needs to execute X times. That's an artificial constraint that I think AWS architects could work around, with a setting that allows multiple requests to queue at a single lambda instance.  That would give users more flexibility and control over their AWS costs and their quality of service.